# How to add commentaries to Glue on an AWS EMR using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I'm having a problem where I cannot find a way to save commentaries on glue metadata with Pyspark.

Currently I create new tables using :

```
df.write \
        .saveAsTable(
            'db_temp.tb_temp',
            format='parquet',
            path='s3://datalake-123/table/df/',
            mode='overwrite'
        )
```

So if possible, I would like to add the comments in glue using code, just like the picture bellow shows :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify existing schema of dataframe by adding required comment. After schema modification, create new dataframe using modified schema and write dataframe as table.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'abc'), (2, 'def')], ["id", "name"])
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False, {"comment": "This is ID"}), 
                 StructField("name", StringType(), True, {"comment": "This is name"})])

df_with_comment = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
df_with_comment.write.format('parquet').saveAsTable('mytable')

spark.sql('describe mytable').show()

+--------+---------+------------+
|col_name|data_type|     comment|
+--------+---------+------------+
|      id|      int|  This is ID|
|    name|   string|This is name|
+--------+---------+------------+
```